# Unity - Ambient Occlusion artefacts

Tags: unity, shaders, global-illumination, ambient-occlusion

When I create two cubes from Unity > Component menu. And turn on AO the bottom cube is not shaded properly. I mean the upper cube is alright but the bottom cube does not have any shadow present. What am I doing wrong ?

Lighting setup:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce `Indirect Resolution` under Baked GI. Bake with these setup.

Modified upon your setup:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Also close the corners if possible.